# Simple web "live chat" software (LAMP stack) that integrates with Jabber/Aim

Tags: php, ajax, chat, xmpp

I've looked for this a few times in the past, to no avail. I would like a simple `php/ajax` web chat interface, that, and this is the critical part, will interface with my `IM client (Pidgin)` ... via Jabber or Aim. `Plugoo` is almost what I want, except it is hosted, and flash based. Flash-based would be OK if not ideal, but hosted isn't.

Note that I don't just need notifications, but I want a user of the website who clicks "live chat" to get a chat interface and my IM client allows me to interact with them.

This is super handy for those of us that want to provide live support to clients who do not use IM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wouldn't be that hard, if you implement the Oscar protocol that AIM uses. It's not very complex, and that would allow you to build a nice web based AIM client for your website. There may be a 3rd party solution that you could use, but as far as I know, Oscar is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 9):

(Disclaimer: I work for [Jabber, Inc.](http://www.jabber.com/), the commercial company behind the product I'm about to pimp.)

[image: JabberWerx AJAX]
<sub>(source: [jabber.com](http://www.jabber.com/images/GroupChatAJAXThumb.png))</sub>

The [JabberWerx AJAX](http://www.jabber.com/CE/JabberWerxAJAXLibrary) libraries do exactly what you want.  You include a reference to a Javascript library, add a div tag where you want the chat to go, and add a couple lines of configuration javascript to hook the two together.  There's also a one-to-one mode.  User accounts can be created on the fly if you like, as well.

Sorry for the ad, but I think it's exactly what you want.

Comment: No.  It is now called the "Cisco AJAX XMPP Library", or CAXL.  No, I didn't choose the name.  I think you have to be a customer of Cisco Unified Presence Server (CUPS) or WebEx Connect to get access.  Failing that, use Strophe (http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/)

Answer (score 2):

I think that http://www.plupper.com is exactly you are looking for

Comment: Great software, free for 1 operator

Comment: Unfortunatley very unreliable. No wonder because it is free.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/), it should be easy to get this to work, particularly if you have a copy of [Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://amzn.to/9zlZsK), by [Jack Moffitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Moffitt).

Comment: Yes, I added a competing answer for a "competing" product, but it might be a better fit for folks that aren't Cisco customers.

Answer (score 0):

How much does this product cost? Re [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114590/simple-web-live-chat-software-lamp-stack-that-integrates-with-jabber-aim/115453#115453) from Joe Hildebrand.

Comment: Sorry for the weasel-y answer, but it depends.  Please contact our sales department.  http://www.jabber.com/CE/ContactUs has a bunch of ways to contact us.

Comment: It will be very hard for users of this website to understand if your answer is acceptable if we have no idea how much the software costs. Can you tell me, what is the price range?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Leave this in a comment to his answer, your question or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

By far the fastest way I can think of would be to add a [Google Talk gadget](http://www.google.com/support/talkgadget/bin/answer.py?answer=86171) to your page.  You will need a gmail account yourself, but visitors to your page don't, they can just start chatting.  Google Talk is excellent with Pidgin.

If you wish to roll your own, the Jabber Wiki has a list of web clients for Jabber:

- http://www.jabber.org/web/Clients#Web_Browser

[JWChat](http://blog.jwchat.org/jwchat/) might do what you want.

Comment: I know this is old, just adding a note anyway that this project is discontinued so don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP based solution you can try out building your application with [Jaxl library](http://jaxl.net). We use this library completely to build a hosted service at [Jaxl IM](http://jaxl.im) which integrates with all XMPP client (pidgin, psi, gtalk) on any kind of platform (mobile, desktop, web).

All that we use to build Jaxl IM solution is out open in form of Jaxl library and can be used to build your own custom solutions. Let us know if you need any consultancy/help with your project.